# How to get a name or xpath of save button in the Cordova image capture window in android devices

Tags: android, cordova, automation

I am working on writing test automation scripts for mobile application for android and iPhone.I am having an issue when move forward to write a particular scenario below.

scenario - upload an image by taking a picture by camera on Andriod and iOS device.

Application is developed using Cordova and ionic.For an image capture and upload have done using Cordova plugins.So the obstacle that I am facing, I have to get a Name or xpath of a "SAVE" button(Native view) to write a test script.For example I have to click on the SAVE button.

Please note that I have shared a image for further more details here.

[image]

Your help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you tried "Uiautomatorviewer" http://www.guru99.com/uiautomatorviewer-tutorial.html ?

Comment: @satkunam Hope this should help - http://toolsqa.com/mobile-automation/appium/how-to-inspect-and-automate-webview-in-hybrid-app/

Comment: I have tried Uiautomatorviewer to find out the element class name, Since there are two buttons with same className I have used   driver.findElement(By.linkText("Save")).click(); to get the work done.But I am getting error like this
org.openqa.selenium.UnsupportedCommandException: Invalid locator strategy: link text (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information). Any help ?